# How can I make rbenv recognise '1.9.3-p***' Ruby versions?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to get some Ruby project running and the project is using `.ruby-version` file. That file contains only:

```
1.9.3
```

I installed the latest Ruby 1.9.3:

```
$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p448
```

However when I ran `ruby --version` I got

```
rbenv: version '1.9.3' is not installed
```

To fix this error I listed `~/.rbenv/versions/` and it contained the folder `1.9.3-p448`. I renamed that folder to `1.9.3` and ran `rbenv rehash`. This fixed the problem.

Looks like the `-p448` part (What does it mean? Patch?) confuses rbenv. How can I make it recognise the correct 1.9.3 version without manually renaming the folder in `~/.rbenv`? I could also change `.ruby-version` to `1.9.3-p448`, but that means that the project will depend on my particular "patch" of Ruby 1.9.3, which is bad.

Comment: try 'rbenv rehash' after 'rbenv install 1.9.3-p448'. And then set      'rbenv local 1.9.3-p448'

Comment: Unfortunately `rbenv local 1.9.3-p448` modifies `.ruby-version` file. This isn't the ideal solution since this file is committed into source control. I don't want the project to depend on my particular "patch" of Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: I think it needs to be tracked in the source control. Since everyone should contribute relating to the specific version of ruby.

Comment: This is really confusing to a ruby noob like me :) Even `1.9.3-p0` doesn't map to `1.9.3`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

rbenv doesn't allow this. From the [wiki](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki):

> Other version managers might allow fuzzy version matching on the
>   string read from `.ruby-version` file, e.g. they might allow "1.9.3"
>   (without patch suffix) to match the latest Ruby 1.9.3 release. **rbenv
>   will not support this**, because such behavior is unpredictable and
>   therefore harmful.

[mislav's comment](https://gist.github.com/fnichol/1912050#comment-682506) from *A Common .ruby-version File For Ruby Projects*:

> rbenv is going to support `.ruby-version`, but definitely without any
>   fuzzy matching. Here's why I think fuzzy matching is a bad idea:
>
> 1. Let's suppose I have 1.9.3-p0 installed.
> 2. I put "ruby-1.9" to `.ruby-version` in my project and all is well.
> 3. After some time I install 1.9.3-p300 to try it out and suddenly all my
>      projects marked with "ruby-1.9" automatically upgrade to it. Gems need to
>      be reinstalled, native extensions need to be upgraded, etc. Nightmare.
>
> One of the important reasons why we have version managers is to be precise
>   about versions. rbenv is going to be precise. If you want cute shortcuts &
>   aliases, you can always make symlinks.

### Alternatives

- Override the `.ruby-version` file by setting the `RBENV_VERSION` environment variable (e.g. for the current shell by running `rbenv shell 1.9.3-p448`).
- Symlink `1.9.3` to `1.9.3-p448`, see [rbenv-aliases](https://github.com/tpope/rbenv-aliases) for details.

Comment: Running into this exact problem trying to install Octopress http://octopress.org/docs/setup/. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into this issue when trying to do knife cookbook upload postgresql, so using rbenv-aliases fixed the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#readme). It allows fuzzy matching of Rubies, so `ruby-1.9`, `1.9.3` and `jruby` should all just work.

Comment: Although chruby is great, this should probably be a comment.